# How to display single quotes on MySQL POST

Tags: php, mysql

How to display single quotes on select MySQL?
I had this example:

```
$var=$_POST['street']; 
echo $var;//it prints: "street.....", while it should print: "street.....",  '1st avenue'
```

In the DB this field is : `"street.....",  '1st avenue'`.
But it prints only: `"street.....",`
Please anybody help me.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make sense. This has nothing to do with escaping, or you're **really** screwing things up badly.

Comment: **it prints: "street.....", while it should print: "street....."** what is the difference?

Comment: sorry, my fault, i edited the question. I tried to use `mysql_real_escape_string` before the insert, but the same result. The single quotes are inserted in DB, but not displayed, when i do select it.

Comment: It would help to diagnose this if you gave us the code you're using to select the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
echo htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you store information in the database, you should use prepared statements with PDO or mysqli. That way you don't have to worry about special characters (assuming you are using utf-8).

When you want to output variables to html, you should always use `htmlspecialchars($var)` to make sure you don't break the html when there are characters like `<`, `>`, `'`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Neither mysql nor PHP has a relation to this problem

1. HTML attributes have to be **quoted**
2. contents of HTML attribute have to be escaped using **htmlspecialchars()**